# Extend Q&A Voting system to Documentation Edits

Tags: feature-request, edits, documentation

*Edit: Fleshed out some ideas.*

**TLDR: The voting system works well for voting for Q&A answers. I think it could work well in Documentation, voting for edits.**

There has been a lot of [discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328519/issues-with-edits-and-reviewing-edits-on-documentation) about issues with the accept/reject system for proposed changes, i.e. too much bad documentation getting approved, and [very good documentation getting deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329596/examples-deleted-from-documentation?cb=1).

It strikes me that one reason for these issues is that any accept/reject thresholds are somewhat arbitrary. Ideally these thresholds would reflect the content being modified, i.e. large thresholds for more popular topics & larger changes, and smaller thresholds for more niche topics and smaller changes.

I suggest a different method for adopting edits that revolves around, instead of an accept/reject system, a voting system.

**How It Might Work**

A user sees need for a change in an existing topic or wishes to add an example. He creates a draft of his changes, describing the problem he sees and his solution, and submits.

This submission act as the OP for an edit thread (similar to the question itself in a question thread). Users can see this suggestion, comment on it, and vote it up or down similar to Q&A.

If other users think up better edits on the same topic, they can post them as alternatives, similar to alternative answers on Q&A, and people can vote for these over the original suggestion. Or they can vote for "No Changes" if they think changes are unnecessary.

**Timing**

Voting on these edits would last at least some minimum time, to make sure that if it's a significant change to a loved example, plenty of people get the chance to vote and voice concerns. If there's significant activity near the end of the voting period, a simple algorithm could determine that the voting period could be extended. If some topics are always getting suggestions, there could be a maximum time for the voting period to prevent changes from never going into effect.

**Quality Control**

Suppose some users like an idea for an edit, but e.g. more experienced users determine that it goes against the purpose of documentation, or an expert suggests that the edit or example is just *wrong*. Experienced users could vote to close the edit, in the same way that questions get closed.

Similarly, suppose an edit is needed *fast* in order to correct a bad mistake on some documentation. Experienced Users could vote to close voting and go ahead and push the edit.

**Conclusion**

This would deal with simultaneous edit proposals, as discussed in [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328519/issues-with-edits-and-reviewing-edits-on-documentation), better. It would allow reviewers to prioritize their time and efforts to meaningful and well-discussed edits by looking at their vote counts. It would allow large or popular edits to get more review before going into effect, making it less likely to have bad changes accepted, and also allows smaller changes to more niche areas (which might not get a lot of attention) to get through without needing an arbitrarily high number of accepts. It would accomplish these things (I think!) in a way that feels natural for stack overflow.

Comment: *"Edit war diplomacy!"* ... Just like Middle East peace might be  a bit complicated. Be interesting to see a sandbox mock up though

Comment: Shouldn't this be a `feature-request` instead of `discussion`?

Comment: I'd like to note that larger changes also can be quite superficial, like multiple formatting changes plus few typos, which end up being not small. Inversely a small change (e.g. one which adds a single sentence about performance impact [and worse, is even incorrect with that]) can be still substantial. Separating changes into small and large is _also_ quite arbitrary.

Comment: Additionally, take in consideration that it must work well for niche tags too (very few reviewers) as well as for very large ones. For Java, there's over hundred simultaneous change proposals… And only a handful _actual, expert_ reviewers. I doubt this can work well...

Comment: @bwoebi good point, but I'm thinking that for niche subjects it'd work at least as well as the current system does. They'd get less votes overall, but the same principle of the edit getting the most point getting pushed through would still work. I also think that having a set amount of time for voting would help for niche subjects as well.

Comment: Additionally, this is hard to balance. What about suggestions which come late in the vote period? What about edits which look largely correct, everyone upvoting it first and then an expert coming along an pointing out it is wrong. There is where your system fails. It is fine for the general suggestions which don't require very specific domain knowledge. But that _that_ point the current review system is fine again. Overall, I'm not too impressed. Or even so called myths: everyone thinks it's a certain way around, few know it's not the case and the expert gets downvoted. [worst-case scenario.]

Comment: On your first point, perhaps set minimum time and some simple algorithm (based on vote rates, etc.) that gauged whether meaningful suggestions & updates were still occurring and if so extended the time-frame.

Comment: Similar to the way Q&A works right now, you could have "votes to close" and similar concepts on bad edits. I think part of my thinking is that this system is just more flexible than the current system.

Comment: @aquirdturtle if we just extend timeframe, then it's probably easy to filibuster an edit for a while. Not for an eternity, but possibly very annoying for every editor. I honestly think a generally improved reviewing system would be better.

Comment: @bwoebi: "but possibly very annoying for every editor." Except for maybe edits that correct bad things, why is there any time pressure?

Comment: @bwoebi Could also set a maximum time for voting to prevent "filibustering" and to segment votes on popular topics if people are always suggesting edits. Not sure what other improvements you have in mind, but I'm of the opinion that many of the other suggested edits (e.g. minimum rep for editing) could be incorporated into this system.