# Incorrect information in Documentation: The Solution

Tags: feature-request, documentation, tag-badges, tag-score

> Note: This is a feature request from [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329574/5644794), slightly modified from [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329557/documentation-update-july-25th/329574?noredirect=1#comment373191_329574).

## The Problem

There is an issue right now with incorrect information being added to documentation.

**Why?**

- 1 rep users with 0 tag score can propose an incorrect change
- 100 rep users with 0 tag score can accept an incorrect change
- Only 1 user needs to accept the change before it goes live
- It takes only 2 users to determine if a change is incorrect and reject it

### Current Proposed Solutions

[Minimum tag score or tag badge required for contributing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328978/minimum-tag-score-for-adding-documentation)

- Pro: Requires some knowledge of the tag being contributed on, not filling the review queue with too many incorrect edits.
- Con: Some users are left out, even if they are experienced but are just starting on SO.

[Minimum tag score or tag badge required for approving changes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328708/5644794)

- Pro: Any user can propose a change, and users above the minimum tag score can approve it. This solves the con from above.
- Con: Tags with not so many users will have proposed changes sitting in the queue for days, waiting for the few people who can to approve the changes.

[Minimum reputation required for approving changes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328708/5644794) (same link as above)

- Pro: Tags with not so many users can get still get the changes approved. This solves the con from above.
- Con: Those with high reputation but unfamiliar with the topic can still approve changes.

---

## The Proposal

**User Criteria**

- Anyone can propose an edit. This allows users to contribute who may be experienced in the topic but haven't contributed on SO proper.
- The top 1000 users in a tag with a tag score of at least 20 are able to review (for less popular tags).
- The users in a tag with a silver tag badge are able to review (for more popular tags).
- Users who have not met this criteria can review with non-binding votes. Once the user has reviewed with a *very high* success rate (think 95% after 50 reviews), the user becomes eligible for reviewing with binding votes.
- Users (even those meeting the criteria) that repeatedly go against what other users say (more than 75% of the time) get banned for a period of time.

**Tag Criteria**

- Change the criteria for a tag to be eligible on documentation from 500 questions to 500 people with a tag score of at least 20 (still working on the exact number). This prevents dead tags like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/zend-framework2/topics), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/wso2/topics), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/webstorm/topics).
- Out of the 5 people who commit to the proposal, two must meet the criteria for binding reviews.

#### For Existing Tags

- For those that meet the criteria, do nothing!
- For those that do not meet the criteria:

  - If it is dead (no one is contributing or 1 person has a bunch of proposed edits that will never be approved), refer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328506/we-need-to-be-able-to-flag-problematic-documentation-tags).
  - Otherwise, I currently do not know of a solution.

Comment: couldn't we just... remove it or fix it?

Comment: _"Users who have not met this criteria can review with non-binding votes. Once the user has reviewed with a very high success rate (think 95% after 50 reviews), the user becomes eligible for reviewing with binding votes."_ As someone who has a hard time contributing answers to my favorite tag (questions are either well answered or too low quality to waste time answering) I really appreciate this part of your request. While I definitely agree that reviewing on docs needs some kind of gate, straight tag badges doesn't feel right.

Comment: @Kendra and this is exactly why I came up with that idea. Rejecting people completely from reviewing just because they haven't been for so long in a given tag on SO q&a, is not really acceptable.

Comment: @Kendra Yes, that was bwoebi's idea.

Comment: @KevinB And let it be discovered by happenstance? How will people know what to trust anymore? If we review things as they are added, mistakes will be much easier to find, and our docs will be much more reliable.

Comment: I think this focuses too much on the existing (review) structure. I don't think that structure is maintainable in the long run. I think we'd better benefit from a tree structure: fixed (elected?) maintainers of a tag, who set out the guidelines to contributing and the bigger picture of the structure of "their" tag, below them appointed reviewers who have the final say about _every_ edit (before and/or after others have approved it). Otherwise we'll keep having monthly repetitions of things that some users miss, which actually already exists but is missed by the ad-hoc reviewers.

Comment: I suspect that "high success rate" is not a thing; and your "going against others" rule has a similar problem. Agreement with other reviewers does not mean correctness. You can easily get robo-reviewers among the top 1000 in a tag. Also, could you clarify what you mean by a non-binding vote? Do you mean that their votes are normal while the "experts" have hammers?

Comment: I don't think timeliness is an issue here with the cons you've listed. Sure, it's noticeable and glaring *now*, but documentation shouldn't change that often. Languages are not updated every single day in production. Most languages take several years to add new stuff... so if a review takes a couple days to pass through or even a week, I don't see that as a problem in the long term.

Comment: How about if after *x* hours, if no binding-vote wielding person has voted, it gets accepted/rejected if there’s *y* approve/reject votes?

Comment: Shameless plug: There is another suggestion related to fixing these sorts of issues: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329634/extend-qa-voting-system-to-documentation-edits :)

Comment: @JF Not a bad solution, could be easily done op top of the current solution. (like: requires at least 2 non-binding review approvals to pass after 24 hours or so)

Comment: @bwoebi That was what I meant (on top of the proposed solution).

Answer (score 5):

It might be a good addition if reviewers could *see* if a proposed change already has one reject vote.

I've come across several edits where, due to my level of knowledge I was not fully sure if an edit was correct but the description seemed well reasoned and the edit itself seemed to hold logical information, thus I approve, only to see that someone else with much better knowledge had voted to reject - which I've now over-ridden.

(It would be good if people voting to reject left a comment as to why - this would be visible in the current system, but this is not happening much. Probably because they already commented in the rejection reason, which, as stated, other reviewers cannot see.)

It would also allow for the case where some reject out of hand based on minor issues such as grammar or punctuation or one incorrect facet of an edit which should actually, following the collaborative ethos of edits in documentation, be fixed in a future effort, thus preserving the rest of a correct edit but refining the grammar (for eg).

For now I personally have taken to leaving a comment instead of voting to reject on edits where I am unsure. But this only leaves the choice up to someone else who might be equally unsure - or in the worst case incorrectly sure that an edit is correct where in fact it is completely wrong!

Answer (score -6):

> Note: This was my original, simpler proposal. I'm posting this as an answer to see if it gains traction and if people are in favor.

## The Simpler Proposal

- Anyone can review, but...
- At least one person with the bronze tag badge or better has to approve/reject the proposed change before it becomes final.

  - The bronze tag badge user takes priority. For example, if two users with a low tag score reject a change, but the bronze tag badge user accepts it, it is accepted and it goes live.
- Change the criteria for a tag to be eligible on documentation to 25 people with at least the bronze tag badge.
- Out of the 5 people who commit to the proposal, two must have at least the bronze tag badge.

<sub>Anywhere I said "bronze tag badge" could be replaced with "25 tag score" or "50 tag score". The bronze tag badge is just a reasonable example that SO already implements and [records users who have it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze).</sub>

Comment: Have seen lots of people with significant rep provide or approve poor quality also

Comment: @charlietfl for these we then can have individual bans. But it's not really feasible to do large-scale bans on many, many unexperienced reviewers.

Comment: Some Stack Exchange sites have relatively few questions per tag, meaning fewer users with bronze badges. Not an issue now, but something to keep in mind for if we ever add Documentation to other sites.

Comment: @Thunderforge we as well have tags with fewer questions on SO. Excatly because of them, requiring bronze badges by default for review is bad.